# Connection Timeout while trying nginx loadbalancing with TRANSPARENT option

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to loadbalance tcp connection to my Server using nginx.I want the server to know the client details so I am using transparent option while connecting to  upstream.But the connection is getting timedout.

```
stream {
         upstream backend  {
                 server 192.168.27.32:8080;
         }


         server {
                 listen 8080;
                 proxy_pass backend;
                 proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
                     }
                                   }
```